# ClassNotFoundException while creating Spark Session

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a Spark Session in Unit Test case using the below code

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("local").master("local").getOrCreate()
```

but while running the tests, I am getting the below error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.GlobalStorageStatistics$StorageStatisticsProvider
```

I have tried to add the dependency but to no avail. Can someone point out the cause and the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of two reasons.
 1. You may have incompatible versions of spark and Hadoop stacks. For example, HBase 0.9 is incompatible with spark 2.0. It will result in the class/method not found exceptions.
 2. You may have multiple version of the same library because of dependency hell. You may need to run the dependency tree to make sure this is not the case.